# Is it possible to define different locations in your NPM package for browser and for server (NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Is it possible to define different locations in your NPM package for browser and for server (NodeJS)?

My code is largely isomorphic, but it is uglified and concatenated for browsers.

Comment: Use two `package.json` files - one for backend and another one for … frontend and store them in two locations

Comment: And have two NPM packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, is that you can't do such thing. Mostly your dependencies are stored under `/node_modules` folder.

You may override this option by running some patches or an installer script.
Here is a [bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3597) raised on Github about this issue.It's is also described in an  official NPM [blogpost](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging)

But don't feel disappointed, you may use [Bower](http://bower.io/) as a dependency injector for your client side code. I prefer it as it feels more semantically and separated:
Bower for the front end, NPM for the back end.

Moreover, NPM packages are built for CommonJs only, Bower packages instead are more plug and play solutions